# Autosave Form along with image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, autosave

Can anybody suggest me a jquery plugin that will auto save html forms data to LocalStorage to restore them after browser crashes,tabs closings or other disasters ?

I have used [this](https://github.com/BenGriffiths/jquery-save-as-you-type) one,its works fine,but it does not save image ?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, you could keep that component but extend what you need to cover the image upload. I'm assuming you want it on the 'change' event of the file input so:

```
<input type="file" id="myimage" name="myimage" />
```

**EDIT** here is a better example - then in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myimage").on('change', function() {
        getImage(this);
    });
});

function getImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log(dataURL);
        var base64Data = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

        localStorage.setItem("myImageData", base64Data);

        setImage(); //set the image from the base64 string.
      }
      img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
}
```

Then to read and set the image back on the page:

```
<img id="myImageElement" src="" />

function setImage() {
    try {
    var imgObj = $("#myimageElement");

    var base64Data = localStorage.getItem("myImageData");
    imgObj.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data;
    }
    catch(e) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer,i will let you know once tested

Comment: I am getting this error "data:image/png;base64,null" by using this snippet

Comment: its my bad,i am still getting this error ""data:image/png;base64,null",Its seems that image is not storing in local storage

Comment: strange. that worked for me. perhaps a browser specific restriction?

Comment: Yes it might be.,but now i can see the base64 string,on change function
This is how i am calling those functions.
$(document).ready(function() {
            setImage();
            $("#myimage").on('change', function() {
                getImage(this);

            });
Perhaps i am not calling the setimage() function properly.

Comment: set image should be called after. put the call straight after `localStorage.setItem("myImageData", base64Data);`